# Fonts are parsed in one way but rendered in a different way

Tags: css, html, cache, parse, fonts

Nginx 1.10.3, WordPress 4.9.1, Elementor 1.8.11. A subdomain site.

### The problem

**Global fonts** appear fine inside Elementor view but not outside of it. That is to say: When you click "Edit this page with Elementor" global fonts like *Assistant* for headings or *Open Sans Hebrew* for general text appear fine but the moment you quit, all the site is in *Arial*.

### Here's what I did trying to solve it:

1. Unselecting the option that disables Elementor global fonts, and saving the changes.
2. Clicking "Regenarate CSS", and saving changes.
3. Flush all caches in site (`cd /var/www/html/test.example.com && sudo wp cache flush`).
4. Flush browser cache.

I've checked the course with both TwentySeventeen and my own theme (Blankslate). The problem doesn't seem to be theme related.

### Notes

- This problem happens from three browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).
- This problem is extremely wired given that in HTML source code, the fonts are parsed correctly (inspection shows *Assistant* for headings or *Open Sans Hebrew* for general text) and yet it is rendered differently, in *Arial*.
- The site's theme is *Blankslate* - the most minimal theme ever and there are no CSS customizations whatsoever.

---

### My question

Let me clarify that this is not a question about the pagebuilder Elementor. This is a question about the principle of why fonts are parsed correctly but rendered otherwise.

What might cause that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due that a caching plugin (Autoptimize) removed Google Fonts.

I have unselected the option to remove Google fonts there and now the problem is no more.

I will never again let any caching plugin remove this. It's totally redundant when you have a good theme and right theming, in 2017.